# Why can't I install OpenCV using pip on my Mac 12.0.1 (Monterey)?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pip

When I tried install OpenCV using python pip, it showed this:

```
Remainder of file ignored
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (20.3.4)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.3.1-py3-********* (1.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.3.4
    Uninstalling pip-20.3.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.4
Successfully installed pip-21.3.1

*Mine*-MacBook-Air ~ % pip install cv2
Error processing line 1 of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/********:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen **********bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored

Error processing line 1 of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/*******************:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<********.bootsrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2
```

I don't know why even if I try reinstalling python, nothing happens!

I am on Macbook Air 'version is given above' and even with python 10.1 (latest current version) nothing happens!

My pip version is also the latest one (you can find it in the above command).

Moreover this problem doesn't happen with some packages, it only happens with a few packages like open cv (cv2). Also, the command used by me to install it was '' PIP install cv2 ''. And please don't recommend me to upgrade my python version, cause I have tried it already and it showed the same thing!

Comment: you really ought to show some care in how you copy-paste terminal output. this was completely garbled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+find+a+version+that+satisfies+the+requirement+cv2+from+versions%3A+none

Comment: How and where are you trying to install on your mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try `pip install opencv-python`** instead of `pip install cv2`

Comment: THANK YOU VERYYYYYY MUCHHHHHHHH. it actually workeddddd!!!!!!    THANKKK YOUUU :)

Comment: your answer addresses (and solves) the issue but do be careful with *asking* for clarification in an answer. that's best put in the comments.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I was trying that before but was unable to do so. Hence, had to put it here.

Comment: @be_real Understood. Now that you have enough rep to comment anywhere, I'd suggest editing your answer to remove that, and request the clarification (if you still care about it) in a comment. You managed to get away with it this time, but keep in mind that attempts to circumvent barriers like this are generally frowned upon here.